# any way for auto-tab in mysql?

Tags: 13.04, mysql, auto-completion

Using MySQL version 5.5 in Ubuntu 13.04.is there any way for enabling auto-completion with <kbd>TAB</kbd> in mysql ?

I'd like to auto-tab for table names,database names,commands etc ,.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the [auto-rehash](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_auto-rehash) option in MySQL:

> Enable automatic rehashing. This option is on by default, which
>   enables database, table, and column name completion. Use
>   --disable-auto-rehash to disable rehashing. That causes mysql to start faster, but you must issue the rehash command if you want to use name
>   completion.
>
> To complete a name, enter the first part and press Tab. If the name is
>   unambiguous, mysql completes it. Otherwise, you can press Tab again to
>   see the possible names that begin with what you have typed so far.
>   Completion does not occur if there is no default database.